# How can I make letters in a word appear as underscores for a Hangman game?

Tags: java

I am not able to figure out how to compare what the user guessed to the letters in the word and change the blanks to the letters guessed.

```
package hangman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangMan {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // user intro
        System.out.println("Hello welcome to HangMan");
        System.out.println("The obecjt of this game is to guess all the letters of the word.");
        System.out.println("You get three tries");

        //create an arraylist to store the words that will be guessed
        ArrayList<String> wordBank = new ArrayList<>();

        //assign words to the wordbank in the array list 
        wordBank.add("car");
        wordBank.add("house");
        wordBank.add("girl");
        wordBank.add("boy");
        wordBank.add("farm");

        //create the random object generator  
        Random rand = new Random();

        //this variable holds the random number generated
        int numberStored;
        numberStored = rand.nextInt(5);

        //the random number generated will link to the index of the arraylist to generate the random word
        String randomWord;
        randomWord = wordBank.get(numberStored);

        //display dots to show number of letters in the word
        for (int j = 0; j < randomWord.length(); j++) {
            System.out.printf("_ ");
        }
        //create scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //this while loop controls the number of guesses
        int wrongGuesses = 0;
        while (wrongGuesses != 3) {
            //prompt 
            System.out.printf("Guess a letter you think is in the word");

            //create a variable to hold the guessed letter
            String guessLetter = input.nextLine();

            //check to see if guessed letter is in the random word 
            boolean value = randomWord.contains(guessLetter);

            // if else statment to decide what to do
            if (value == true) {
                System.out.println("Letter " + guessLetter + " is correct");
                System.out.println("Now guess a different letter");
                //find the position of the guessed letter in the word
                //char g =  randomWord.charAt(0);
                //loop through all the letters of the word
                //for (int j = 0; j < randomWord.length(); j++){
                //  if (gueesLetter.eq)
                //    int comparedstring
                //}
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry "+guessLetter+ " is not in the word");
                System.out.println("Try again");
                wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
            }
            System.out.println("random word = " + randomWord);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to match the guessed letters with and replace them in the _ _ _ setup.

Comment: Please do your homework alone. You supposed to learn. Copypaste from SO is not learning.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentWord = "hello";

    List<Character> guessedCharacters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    guessedCharacters.add('e');
    guessedCharacters.add('o');
    guessedCharacters.add('q');     
    guessedCharacters.add('i');

    System.out.println(maskString(guessedCharacters, currentWord));
}

private static String maskString(List<Character> guessedCharacters, String currentWord){
    char[] currentWordList = currentWord.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder maskedString = new StringBuilder();
    int tempLength;

    for(char letter : currentWordList){
        tempLength = maskedString.length(); //store the current length of the string
        for(char guessedLetter : guessedCharacters){
            if(letter == guessedLetter){
                maskedString.append(letter);
            }
        }
        if(tempLength == maskedString.length()){// if the string is still the same length, 
                                         // then the tested letter hasn't been guessed yet.
            // if the letter hasn't been guessed the we 'mask' it with an underscore.
            maskedString.append('_');
        }
    }

    return maskedString.toString();
}
```

Output:

> _e__o

Comment: This is a bit backwards. Surely you wouldn't want to display all the letters in the word which the player hadn't guessed

Comment: @shaun I have updated my answer to provide a solution